# Show ToolTip with ComboBox (dropdownmenu)

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I am showing a little tooltip, but if I change the selecteditem/text in the dropdownmenu, tooltip shows the old text and the new text. I want it to show only the new text.

```
private void optionsvalueComboBox_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip buttonToolTip = new ToolTip();
    buttonToolTip.ToolTipTitle = "Value";
    buttonToolTip.UseFading = true;
    buttonToolTip.UseAnimation = true;
    buttonToolTip.IsBalloon = true;
    buttonToolTip.ShowAlways = true;
    buttonToolTip.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
    buttonToolTip.InitialDelay = 1000;
    buttonToolTip.ReshowDelay = 0;

    buttonToolTip.SetToolTip(optionsvalueComboBox, optionsvalueComboBox.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried digging in the `MouseHover` event of a `ComboBox` and looks like it doesn't work normally as we expect. The `MouseHover` is in fact **fired** only when you move the mouse over the `drop down button` if your `ComboBox` has style of `dropdown`. The simplest solution for this is change your combobox style to `dropdownlist` like this:

```
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

However that kind of style will make the `ComboBox` readonly. If that's not what you want, there is a work-around for you is to use the event `MouseMove` with a `Timer` to mimic the `MouseHover`, here is the code for you:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  public Form1(){
    InitializeComponent();
     t.Interval = 600;
     t.Tick += (se, ev) => {
       buttonToolTip.SetToolTip(comboBox1, (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem);
       t.Stop();
     };
     //init the buttonToolTip
     buttonToolTip.ToolTipTitle = "Value";
     buttonToolTip.UseFading = true;
     buttonToolTip.UseAnimation = true;
     buttonToolTip.IsBalloon = true;
     buttonToolTip.ShowAlways = true;
     buttonToolTip.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
     buttonToolTip.InitialDelay = 1000;
     buttonToolTip.ReshowDelay = 0;
     //register MouseMove event handler for your comboBox1
     comboBox1.MouseMove += (se, ev) => {                    
       //Restart the timer every time the mouse is moving
       t.Stop();
       t.Start();
     };
  }
  Timer t = new Timer();
  ToolTip buttonToolTip = new ToolTip();
}
```

Comment: Old one, yes but I just needed this for some legacy stuff. If combo is editable then you can just use MouseEnter and MouseLeave events. Works for both editable text area and actual button.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming what you don't like is the tooltip text changing from the old text to the new text...

The reason it's doing that is because you are creating a new tooltip instance on every hover event. Every time the hover event is fired, the old tooltip instance is replaced with a new one which is why you see both. To fix this, put the declaration outside the event, like this:

```
ToolTip buttonToolTip = new ToolTip();

private void optionsvalueComboBox_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonToolTip.ToolTipTitle = "Value";
    buttonToolTip.UseFading = true;
    buttonToolTip.UseAnimation = true;
    buttonToolTip.IsBalloon = true;
    buttonToolTip.ShowAlways = true;
    buttonToolTip.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
    buttonToolTip.InitialDelay = 1000;
    buttonToolTip.ReshowDelay = 0;

    buttonToolTip.SetToolTip(optionsvalueComboBox, optionsvalueComboBox.Text);
  }
```

Now the same tooltip is being used with the wording simply being replaced. Let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 2):

A complete working example:

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public RECT(Rectangle rect)
    {
        Left = rect.Left;
        Top = rect.Top;
        Right = rect.Right;
        Bottom = rect.Bottom;
    }

    public Rectangle Rect
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle(Left, Top, Right - Left, Bottom - Top);
        }
    }

    public Point Location
    {
        get
        {
            return new Point(Left, Top);
        }
    }

    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}

public class ToolTipComboBox: ComboBox
{
    #region Fields

    private ToolTip toolTip;
    private bool _tooltipVisible;
    private bool _dropDownOpen;
    #endregion

    #region Types

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
    public struct COMBOBOXINFO
    {
        public Int32 cbSize;
        public RECT rcItem;
        public RECT rcButton;
        public ComboBoxButtonState buttonState;
        public IntPtr hwndCombo;
        public IntPtr hwndEdit;
        public IntPtr hwndList;
    }

    public enum ComboBoxButtonState
    {
        // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global
        StateSystemNone = 0,
        // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global
        StateSystemInvisible = 0x00008000,
        // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global
        StateSystemPressed = 0x00000008
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hWnd, ref COMBOBOXINFO pcbi);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private IntPtr HwndCombo
    {
        get
        {
            COMBOBOXINFO pcbi = new COMBOBOXINFO();
            pcbi.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(pcbi);
            GetComboBoxInfo(Handle, ref pcbi);
            return pcbi.hwndCombo;
        }
    }

    private IntPtr HwndDropDown
    {
        get
        {
            COMBOBOXINFO pcbi = new COMBOBOXINFO();
            pcbi.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(pcbi);
            GetComboBoxInfo(Handle, ref pcbi);
            return pcbi.hwndList;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public new DrawMode DrawMode
    {
        get { return base.DrawMode; }
        set { base.DrawMode = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ctor

    public ToolTipComboBox()
    {
        toolTip = new ToolTip
        {
            UseAnimation = false,
            UseFading = false
        };

        base.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        DrawItem += OnDrawItem;
        DropDownClosed += OnDropDownClosed;
        DropDown += OnDropDown;
        MouseLeave += OnMouseLeave;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void OnDropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dropDownOpen = true;
    }

    private void OnMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResetToolTip();
    }

    private void ShowToolTip(string text, int x, int y)
    {
        toolTip.Show(text, this, x, y);
        _tooltipVisible = true;
    }

    private void OnDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cbo = sender as ComboBox;
        if (e.Index == -1) return;

        // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
        string text = cbo.GetItemText(cbo.Items[e.Index]);
        e.DrawBackground();

        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, e.Font, e.Bounds.Location, SystemColors.Window);

            if (_dropDownOpen)
            {
                Size szText = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, cbo.Font);
                if (szText.Width > cbo.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth && !_tooltipVisible)
                {
                    RECT rcDropDown;
                    GetWindowRect(HwndDropDown, out rcDropDown);

                    RECT rcCombo;
                    GetWindowRect(HwndCombo, out rcCombo);

                    if (rcCombo.Top > rcDropDown.Top)
                    {
                        ShowToolTip(text, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y - rcDropDown.Rect.Height - cbo.ItemHeight - 5);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ShowToolTip(text, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + cbo.ItemHeight - cbo.ItemHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ResetToolTip();
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, e.Font, e.Bounds.Location, cbo.ForeColor);
        }

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }

    private void OnDropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dropDownOpen = false;
        ResetToolTip();
    }

    private void ResetToolTip()
    {
        if (_tooltipVisible)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
            toolTip.SetToolTip(this, null);
            _tooltipVisible = false;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```